# How to upload a file to a user after a front-end action in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, coffeescript

I'm working on a project built entirely in node.js and coffeescript.  I want to allow the user to export a CSV of several different collections in my Mongo DB by clicking a button on my website.
   I believe the best way to do this would be to make an ajax call to my node.js backend and have that call return somefile.csv to the user.  I'm at a loss at how to do this though, and there are so many conflicting resources.  Here's the stub of how I think things should work:

```
exports.exportToCSV = (req, res) ->
  console.log 'Inside exportToCSV'

  # Create a dynamic csv file
  # How to?
  # Set the response headers
  # How to? 
  # Attach the newly created CSV
  # How to?
  # Write the response
  res.write('somefile.csv')
  res.end()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Express (and I'd say you need a pretty big excuse not to), everything after creating the CSV is a piece of cake:

```
res.download 'somefile.csv'
```

As the [Express docs explain](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), that's shorthand for

```
res.attachment 'somefile.csv'
```

(which sets the headers) and

```
res.sendfile 'somefile.csv'
```

If you want to understand how it all works, here's the source: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js

As to creating a CSV, I've never had to do this, but you can't go wrong [searching npm](http://search.npmjs.org/) for "csv".

Comment: This let's me send back data to the front-end, but it only sends the contents of the file as part of the response.  I'm really looking to have the ajax call open up a save dialog on success.

Comment: Add a form to the DOM and make that form submit after the file is ready on the server: http://particletree.com/notebook/ajax-file-download-or-not/

Comment: You might also want to look at [InstantIco](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/instantico), a small project I did for Node Knockout that does Ajax downloading.